# Route does not change for different Param ID, even though key is different

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react Router application, which so far only have two routes.

```
<Router history={history}>
        <div>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="/pdfviewer/:index" component={PdfViewer} />
      </Switch>
      </div>     
      </Router>
```

in my sidebar i map all the component to be `PdfViewer` down like this

```
const files = data.map((file, i) =>{
      return(
        <FileItem file={file} key={`${i}`} name={`file number ${i+1}`} index={i+1} /> 
        )
    })
```

inside each `FileItem` i have a NavLink to render to the component with the given index.

```
<ListItem button component={Link} to={{pathname:`/pdfviewer/${index}`, state: {fileObject: fileObject, fileLineObjects: fileLineObjects}}}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <AssignmentIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={name} />
      </ListItem>
```

whenever the route changes, a new component does not mount, but when i reload the browser the site updates. Why does this happen, when i provide a new key to each component?

Comment: Make use ComponentDidUpdate life cycle hook to detect the changes of index  in the route on pdfViewer component.

Comment: As you can you I'm using functional components @ChinnaM.. so i can't do that, but great input